# Triggering a button click through code

Tags: c#, events

So I have the following code for when the "Add player" button is clicked

```
private void addPlayerBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do some code
}
```

I want to trigger this code from my SDK however. Here is what I have tried

```
private void command()
{       
    addPlayerBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e);          
}
```

I get lots of errors as soon as I put in the line

```
 addPlayerBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Could somebody please tell me how to write the code so that I can trigger an event by just writting it in code?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For one, when calling a method, you don't declare the type of the parameter, just the value.

So this:

```
addPlayerBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Should be

```
addPlayerBtn_Click_1(sender, e);
```

Now, you'll have to declare `sender` and `e`. These can be actual objects, if you have event args to pass, or:

```
addPlayerBtn_Click_1(null, EventArgs.Empty);
```

The above can be used in either WinForms or ASP.NET. In the case of WinForms, you can also call:

```
addPlayerBtn.PerformClick();
```

Answer (score 7):

When you call a function, you provide actual arguments, which are values, not formal arguments, which are types and parameter names.

Change

```
addPlayerBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

to

```
addPlayerBtn_Click_1(addPlayerBtn, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private void command()
 {     
   addPlayerBtn.PerformClick();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
addPlayerBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Should be:

```
addPlayerBtn_Click_1(this, new EventArgs());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
addPlayerBtn_Click_1(null, null);
```

This works if you don't need the information in `sender` and `e`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the sender or the events so you can call the function directly like this:

```
addPlayerBtn_Click_1(null, null);
```