# click to button automaticly in winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication

**Program.cs**

```
var loginForm = new Login("username", "password");
    Application.Run(loginForm);
```

When I run program, program displays username and password automatically in username and password textboxes.

I have also "**login**" button. How to click **login button automaticly** when i program run?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: There must be hundereds of such questions ([click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14024963/1997232)). The problem is to find the right word: *automaticALly*, *programmatically*, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call your event Handler directly.

```
this.BtnClick(null, null);
```

Another solution would be:

```
private void Form1_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Button1.PerformClick(); 
}
```

Comment: can i call as "                loginForm.btnLogin.Click(null, null);" ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You need to call PerformClick or the function assigned to the click Event Handler.

Comment: var loginForm = new Login("hasan.kurulu@outlook.com", "123456");
                Application.Run(loginForm);
                loginForm.btnLogin.PerformClick(); solved problem thanks for help.

Comment: `this.BtnClick(null, null);` is a dubious soultion; if you want to call BtnClick you should do it like `this.BtnClick(Button1, EventArgs.Empty);` To avoid complications put `Button1.PerformClick(); `