# Possible to initiate and await for PerformClick of a form component from another component?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous

I'm having a very hard time finding if it is possible to perform a virtual click on a C# form element from another element, and wait for it to complete before proceeding.

As an example (unfortunately incomplete), what I'm trying to do is this

```csharp
  private async void btn_my_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      await Task.Run(() => radio_button_special.PerformClick()); // https://stackoverflow.com/q/14024963

      // once this is done, proceed with rest of processing
      do_rest_of_processing();
  }
```

When I click the button in Debug run, VS2019 breaks with "InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'radio_button_special' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

However if I just run the exe outside of Visual Studio debug, the button seems to work (i.e. I can see in the application that radio_button_special.PerformClick() completes first, and do_rest_of_processing() runs after - and I do not get an explicit exception running like that, so it seems to work as I imagined it).

But that exception scares me, so I'd like to get rid of it - and I've tried remedying like this, which I've attempted building from other snippets on SO:

```csharp
  private async void btn_my_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // first, I want to call the function otherwise called
      // when the radio button is clicked, and wait for it to complete
      radio_button_special.Invoke((MethodInvoker)async delegate
      {
          await Task.Run(() => radio_button_special.PerformClick()); // https://stackoverflow.com/q/14024963
      });
      // once this is done, proceed with rest of processing
      do_rest_of_processing();
  }
```

Now, this function already gives a warning in the VS2019 IDE:

> warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

... and if I debug run the example, I get the stack trace:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
  HResult=0x80131604
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   ...
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at my_test.Program.Main() in D:\work\bbs\BBS_DEV\BAPS_git\my_test\Program.cs:line 28

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.Handle.get()
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.InternalHandle.get()
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.Update()
    System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.ResetFlagsandPaint()
    System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton.PerformClick()
    my_test.main_form.btn_my_Click.AnonymousMethod__122_1() in main_form.cs
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    ...
    [Call Stack Truncated]

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'radio_button_special' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

So, basically the same problem as earlier.

So, how could I call a C# form component handler (e.g. click) function from another form component handler, wait for it to complete, and then call another function - without it raising an exception?

Comment: `Task.Run` queues the method you give to run on a Thread Pool thread. So you are still accessing the control from another thread even though you perform an invoke.

Comment: What is the point of calling `Task.Run()`, to then invoke right back to the UI Thread? You can simply call `radio_button_special.PerformClick()`. Or, better still, move the code in the `Click` handler of your RadioButtons to a method that you can mark `async`, if / when needed (and if actually possible or meaningful in your context)?

Comment: @Jimi - I'm just looking for a way to do the following: if I click on the radio button, and it is not checked, only when it gets checked, it runs a (longish) process that uses USB. I want then, when clicking the button, also the checkbox to be "clicked" - with the result that the radio button is unchecked, it becomes visually checked (and only then, the USB process is also ran). But then, I must "await" for this in the button, because the button then should run another USB process, and the second must not interfere with the first.

Comment: So, I'm just looking for *anything* that will allow me to call the checkbox handler from the button handler, wait for it to complete, and then run something else; from my searches, I've seen "invoke" and "task" being used, but I do not really understand their difference - and I really cannot find any example  of how to call one handler from another while waiting for it to complete.

Comment: What CheckBox? Do you mean the RadioButton, or is there another Control involved? -- It depends on what *wait* means here. Wait *asynchronously* (i.e., the UI is not blocked in the meanwhile)? Move the code you have in the event handler of the RadioButton to its own method (you should), mark this method `async` and there `await Task.Run()` the code that deals with the USB. Await this method in `btn_my_Click()`; when `Task.Run()` returns, do whatever else is needed. If also the RadioButton is meant to call the same method (the now `async` one), use a flag to signal it shouldn't

Comment: Thanks @Jimi - sorry about the mention of CheckBox, I'm tired and my attention is slipping unfortunately; I meant the radio button. I was not thinking of the UI being blocked, thanks for reminder - actually, I'd be fine with UI being blocked, since these operations are some 2-3 seconds long, so it is fine. The accepted answer (rather, my edit) is what ended up working for me.

Comment: Instead of all this `Task.Run`+`Invoke(MethodInvoker)` trickery, it might be simpler to just do `Application.DoEvents();` before the `radioButton1.PerformClick()`. The [`Application.DoEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.doevents) is considered bad practice, but what you ended up doing is probably just as bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Task.Run` queues the method you give to run on a thread pool thread. So you are still accessing the control from another thread even though you perform an invoke. Instead, you should call the `Control.Invoke` inside the `Task.Run`.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        radioButton1.Invoke(() => radioButton1.PerformClick());
    });
}
```

---

EDIT: what worked for OP poster was:

```csharp
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        radioButton1.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { radioButton1.PerformClick(); });
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh, I so wished the original answer worked for me - unfortunately I got "Error CS1660 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Delegate' because it is not a delegate type" ... however, after some messing about, found another expression that worked for me, and updated the answer - thanks a ton, that was great help for me!

Comment: I used .Net 7 and forgot that you use .Net Framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to call one method from another, then this would work:

```
private void btn_my_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  radio_button_special.PerformClick();
  do_rest_of_processing();
}
```

`Task.Run` queues work to the thread pool, which is incorrect here.

If you have long-ish work to do, it's nicer to your users if you run that work on a thread pool thread. The proper solution in that case is to refactor your code so that there's another method that can be called by both the radio button click and this button click.